# How to set-up a pair of conditional triggers that only answer to eachother?

Tags: pine-script

So essentially I'm looking at setting up a conditional trigger for a sell entry - that is paired with an opposing condition to exit that position. I've used a variable to isolate and only print 1 entry condition and now need to add another variable so that I can keep track of when I'm "in a position" so that when I encounter the exit condition, "in a position" + "exit condition" can trigger an exit alert.

```
// Setting Variables
var shortsell_triggered = false
var shortsell_close_triggered = false

// Entry Condition
shortsell_condition = crossunder(close, ema5)

// Conditional Alert (Triggering only 1 Alert)
shortsell_alert = shortsell_condition and not shortsell_triggered

// Changing Variables (if alerted, then trigger changes to true; otherwise, it stays false)
shortsell_triggered := shortsell_alert ? true : shortsell_triggered

// Since shortsell_triggered changes per bar calculation, by the time the exit condition triggers, the      variable "shortsell_triggered" will already be false again so I have to 'copy' the true value to another variable while in position so that it can scan for an exit. 

if shortsell_triggered == true
shortsell_close_primed := true

// Plotting Entry
plotshape(shortsell_alert)

// Exit Condition
shortsell_close_condition = crossover(close, ema5)

// Condition Alert (Triggering only 1 Exit Alert)
shortsell_close_alert = shortsell_close_condition and shortsell_close_primed and not     shortsell_close_triggered

// Plotting Exit
plotshape(shortsell_close_alert)
```

I have successfully loaded up only 1 entry alert on the chart, but there seems to be a large number of exit conditions that I can't seem to figure out.

My solution was to try to set a different variable for "priming" the exit condition so that it sets to 'true' when the entry gets alerted, but does not revert to false when the entry condition no longer exists. That way, once triggered, even if the entry condition doesn't exist (the entry is already plotted) the new variable can be used to track the exit conditions.